# howto initialize a wcf class

Tags: wcf, class, initialization

Im trying to use a Class in a WCF service. When im calling the

```
u.attributeChanges.Add(a);
```

i get:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

If create the classes in the client application it's working.

UpdateChanges Class

```
[DataContract]
public class UpdateChanges
{

    private void Initialize()
    {

        this.attributeChanges = new List<AttributeChanges>();

    }

    public UpdateChanges()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string objectGuid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Utilities.ObjectTypes objectType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public  Utilities.ChangeType changeType{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<AttributeChanges> attributeChanges { get; set; }


    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {

        this.Initialize();

    }


}
```

AttributeChanges class

```
[DataContract]
public class AttributeChanges
{
    [DataMember]
    public string attributeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string attributeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Client Code:

```
Service.DirsyncServiceClient proxyClient;
proxyClient = Utilities.GetProxy("http://192.168.1.45/vDir/Service.svc");

Service.UpdateChanges u = new Service.UpdateChanges();
Service.AttributeChanges a = new Service.AttributeChanges();
a.attributeName = "Attribute1";
a.attributeValue = "Value1";
u.attributeChanges.Add(a);

proxyClient.SaveObject(u);
```

Anyonw know how to solve this?

Comment: You have a Null Reference Exception, I don't think the problem related to WCF. On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: On u.attributeChanges.Add(a);

Answer (score 0):

You're using a generated client code. 
The problem is that the client generates this code on base of the WSDL xlm. The code in the CTOR doesn't generated in the client because the client can't be aware of this code.

You have a few options- 
 1. Use a shared DLL with the data contract instead of generating it via a web reference.

 2. Implement it yourself in a 'partial' class.

Comment: how would such a partial class look like?

Comment: You can see example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx  The idea of partial classes is to let you write your code into a generated class. If I remember correctly the generated class is already 'partial' so just add a partial class with the same name with your CTOR implementation.